# Issue In Generating wsdl by using apache cxf 2.7.4

Tags: apache, wsdl

Issue in generating wsdl using apache cxf 2.7.4. For complex type, this ref
 attribute is coming:

```
xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:launchConfiguration"
```

I want to dispaly like this :

```
xs:element minOccurs="0" name="launchConfiguration" type="tns:launchConfiguration"
```

It is generating fine in cxf 2.5.2, but not in 2.7.4 Getting following error:

> Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:url, local:“objectname”). Expected elements are <{}objectname>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the above issue by removing jaxb-impl.jar.There was no issue with the cxf jar. With java 6 and above the  JAVA SE libraries contains the implementation for jaxb dependency.